# Get multiple fields in an array linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

In my application a user can have multiple locations. I want to show all the locations of user in a dropdown. I created a model having two fields `UserID` and `Locations`. Locations are array of strings. I want a Linq query to get `UserID` and their `Locations`. Is it possible in Linq?

```
public partial class ModelLocation
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }      
    public string[] Locations{ get; set; }
}
```

In my database records are like

```
UserID   Location
1           A
1           B
2           A
3           B
3           C
3           D
```

Comment: Where is your source data stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var models = db.Locations.GroupBy(l => l.UserId)
.Select(l => new ModelLocation() 
{ 
  UserID = l.Key, 
  Locations = l.Select(l => l.Location).ToArray() 
});
```

Depending on the linq engine you are using (linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities) the query can get really bad performance and result in multiple queries being sent to the DB. A way to solve that is to retrieve the data from the DB first and then perform the grouping in memory instead by introducing a call to `AsEnumerable()`.

```
var models = db.Locations.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(l => l.UserId)
.Select(l => new ModelLocation() 
{ 
  UserID = l.Key, 
  Locations = l.Select(l => l.Location).ToArray() 
});
```

If you want to do any filtering with `Where()` you should do that *before* the call to `AsEnumerable()` to get the filtering done in the DB.

Comment: Thanks Anders, How can I use join in it? I wrote only two fields here.Actually in my model there are a 9 fields. which are coming from different tables.

Comment: If you have the foreign keys/relations properly set up, you can use navigation properties: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Answer (score 0):

```
// these are the raw db objects
List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

var modelLocations = records.GroupBy(i => i.UserID).Select(g => new ModelLocation {
    UserID = g.Key,
    Locations = g.Select(j => j.Location).ToArray()
});
```

Comment: That will not create a `ModelLocation` object.

Comment: you're right, I was just about changing my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.SelectMany()` to achieve such output:

```
var locations = modelLocations.SelectMany(x => x.Select(location => new { x.UserID, location }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = db.UserLocations
            .GroupBy(l => l.UserID)
            .Select(g =>
                     new ModelLocation
                            {
                               UserID = g.Key,
                               Locations = g.Select(l => l.Location).ToArray()
                            });
```